# Detecting reflection on objects or curved images inside images

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, pattern-matching, neural-network, image-recognition

I need to detect reflection on objects (i.e. on a car) or an curved image inside another image. Does anybody know how to do that?

Some examples of what I'm looking for:

[image: window reflection]

[image: car reflection]

Also, I don't need to detect a clear object from that reflection, I jut need to see if there's light reflecting from an object

Comment: nearly everything you see in an image is a reflection. Can you post sample images to show what kind of reflections you mean? For example it might be quite easy to guess specular reflections but it might be very hard to detect clear object reflections.

Comment: I've added them in the question, hope it helps :)

Comment: nearly impossible imho

Comment: What about curve detection? I.e. I could compute an edge image inside an image and detect if there are any curves

Comment: On the 1st image I thought I was seeing through the glass to an outdoors park on a rainy day, but apparently that was the reflection you wish to detect! The car example is a bit easier as the color and orientation changes but still these effects seem quite arbitrary. Why would you need this detection?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't here for a while. It's for an project that I'm working on, but I found another way to solve my problem. Still it would be nice to be able to detect reflection on images :)